# Heroku Ruby supported versions not in rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app is currently using the gem ruby '1.9.3'.
Heroku won't let me update the app.

They list the following as supported Ruby versions:

- 2.4.5 : patchlevel 335, Rubygems: 2.6.14.3
- 2.5.3: patchlevel 105, Rubygems: 2.7.6
- 2.6.1: patchlevel 33, Rubygems: 3.0.1

I'm using Rbenv to manage ruby versions.
If I run $ rbenv install --list, none of those (2.4.5, 2.5.3, 2.6.1) are in the listed versions available.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rbenv versions` shows the list of versions already installed on your computer.

Run `rbenv install 2.4.5` to install it.

Comment: Sorry, updated to show correct command = $ rbenv install --list

Comment: Pick up the nearest one. It does not really matter to have the exactly same version on local.